# Error comparing a random number to the size of a vector

Tags: c++

I'm in a little over my head, and I'm not sure what this error means or what to do about it. Here's my code:

```
class player::deck
{
    public:
        vector<int> deck;
        int draw(){
            int card = srand(time(NULL)) % deck.size();
            deck.erase(deck(begin)+card);
            return card;
        }
};
```

What I'm *trying* to do is make a deck for each player. Cards represented by integers (0 is card 0, 1 is card 1, etc.).

And here's the error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/try3/main.cpp: In member function ‘int player::deck::draw()’:                                                                                                             
/home/ubuntu/workspace/try3/main.cpp:27:54: error: invalid operands of types ‘void’ and ‘std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ to binary ‘operator%’                              
         int card = srand(time(NULL)) % deck.size();                                                                                                                                         
                                                  ^                                                                                                                                          
/home/ubuntu/workspace/try3/main.cpp:28:34: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int>) (<unresolved overloaded function type>)’                                                             
         deck.erase(deck(begin)+card);                                                                                                                                                       
                              ^
```

Any help would be tremendously appreciated. If I'm in the wrong place or I'm using the site incorrectly, please let me know.

Comment: srand doesn't return a random number, it just initializes the random number generator. Hence you are doing void % size_t

Comment: JVApen is right. You need to use rand() after srand()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int card = rand() % deck.size();
```

[srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/): Initialize random number generator

[rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/): Generate random number